# Python Multiprocessing slight slower than Multithreading on Windows

Tags: windows, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing, pyserial

I have been experimenting my code to send "parallel" commands to multiple serial COM ports.

My multi-threading code consists of:

```
global q 
q = Queue()
devices = [0, 1, 2, 3]
for i in devices:
    q.put(i)
cpus=cpu_count() #detect number of cores
logging.debug("Creating %d threads" % cpus)
for i in range(cpus):
    t = Thread(name= 'DeviceThread_'+str(i), target=testFunc1)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
```

and multi-processing code consists of:

```
devices = [0, 1, 2, 3]
cpus=cpu_count() #detect number of cores
pool = Pool(cpus)
results = pool.map(multi_run_wrapper, devices)
```

I observe that the task of sending serial commands to 4 COM ports in "parallel" takes about 6 seconds and multi-processing always always takes a 0.5 to 1 second of additional total run time.

Any inputs on why the discrepancy on a Windows machine?

Comment: Multi processing always has additional overhead vs. multi threading. Multi threading uses the same memory space as the parent process, whereas multi processing needs to allocate new memory for the process. There's probably more factors at play than that, but this overhead is a given.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one, you're not comparing apples to apples. If you want equivalent code, use `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` in your threaded case (which is the same as `multiprocessing.Pool` implemented in terms of threads, not processes), so you're at least using the same basic parallelization model with different internal implementations, not changing everything all at once.

Beyond that, launching the workers and communicating data to them has some overhead, more on Windows than on other systems since Windows can't `fork` to spawn new processes cheaply; it has to spawn a new Python instance and then copy over state via IPC to approximate forking.

Aside from that, you haven't provided enough information; your process and thread based worker functions aren't provided, and could cause significant differences in behavior. Nor have you provided information on how you're performing timing. Similarly, if each worker process needs to reinitialize the COM port communication library, that could involve non-trivial overhead.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. The worker functions are exactly same for both the methods (multithreading & multiprocessing), except the q.put()/q/taskdone() calls in multihtreading. And in each thread instance, I am initializing a new COM port, so it is not actually an overhead, as I am not trying to re-initialize the same COM port. For now, I think I am going ahead with multithreading, as it seems to be quite stable for what I am trying to do, and comparatively quicker too. (using start-stop time difference using time library to time it).